# My preload script doesn't work completely

Tags: jquery

I made a preloader to load in some content with tables and custom scrollbars while a Loading Div covers the area. After that is finished, the load div should disappear.

For some reason the preload disappears before the content is finished loading.

If you try out this [demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia4/) and *click the button at the very top* that says **venues**, you might notice that it doesn't completely wait for everything to be configured before the load div dissapears. Some people may even see the old content for a second or two.

Here is the code I used below. I included comments as well.

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".topCanBeActive", "click", function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // this just handles the css class of buttons
    jQuery(".topCanBeActive").removeClass("topActive");

    // this just handles the css class of buttons
    jQuery(this).addClass("topActive");

    var pageToLoad = '';
    switch( this.id ) {
        case 'all_events_button':
            $('#partypreloader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                pageToLoad = 'events.html';
                configureEvents();
            });
            break;
        case 'all_venues_button': // this is the venues button
            // fade in 'loading' div
            $('#partypreloader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                pageToLoad = 'venues.html';

                // configure tables etc
                configureVenues();
            });
            break;
        case 'event_finder_button':
            pageToLoad = 'search.html';
            break;
    }
    if( '' !== pageToLoad ){
        // just in case, I added the same function
        // to load the preload div here
        $('#partypreloader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
            // load the chosen content in desired div
            $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load( pageToLoad, function() {
                // fade out the preload div
                configureFadeOut();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the configureEvents function, notice I also used some fake loading to cover up the issues.

```
function configureEvents() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {

            // configure table
            $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                headers: {
                    0: { sorter: false }
                },
                widgets: ['zebra']
            });

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                // Configure scrollbar
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

                // Configure table again - I had issues with this
                // so I did it twice
                $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                    headers: {
                        0: { sorter: false }
                    },
                    widgets: ['zebra']
                });

                // Set CSS class for buttons
                jQuery("#all_events_button").addClass("topActive");
                jQuery("#today_button").addClass("timeframeActive");
            }, 150);
        });

        // Preload div fades out
        $("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 200);
}
```

I revised the code to make the preload work to such levels that the code is as complicated as it is. If you spot out something that seems off, please let me know. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: Have you tried putting `$("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");` inside the `load()` callback?

Comment: Hi Šime, but this is basically what `configureFadeOut();` does, as it too is placed in the `load()` callback.

Comment: It's in the `load()` callback? I don't see it...

Comment: Hmm, I'm a begginer so maybe I was wrong this whole time. I thought this was the callback: `$('#whole-ajax-content-one').load( pageToLoad, function() {
                configureFadeOut();
            });`   ?

Comment: Ah, I see. What does the `configureVenues` function look like? Why did you post the code of `configureEvents` instead? I thought venues had the issue, not events...

Comment: There's the same issue with `configureEvents`.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that. The `configureEvents` and `configureVenues` are basically the same except for the fact that they load different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your current code:

```
function configureEvents() {

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {
            // other code
        });

        $("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");

    }, 200);

}
```

As you can see, the `fadeOut` call is **outside** of the `load()` callback, which means that the fade-out occurs **immediately** - it doesn't wait for the `load` event.

Try putting it **inside** the `load` callback (at the end):

```
function configureEvents() {

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {
            // other code

            $("#partypreloader").fadeOut("slow");
        });        

    }, 200);

}
```

---

Btw, what's the time-out for?

Comment: Oh, so very true. Missed that one in my answer.

Comment: What's funny is that I didn't notice this until after freakish also mentioned this. The timeout was a 'fake load' idea to give the code a bit more time to load. However, I noticed that the problem now is that my switch function code load doesn't work, because I also noticed that I'm using my `.load` function twice. Once in the switch function, and once in the `configureEvents` and `configureVenues` function... and removing the `.load` from `configureVenues` actually stops the content from loading - meaning that the switch function load is broken. Okay, back to the drawing board :)

Comment: I'll get some sleep now and get back to it as soon as I wake up. Thanks Šime! :)

Comment: @pufAmuf You do that. I'll go make an omelet. *Yummy*

Answer (score 1):

Is this your current code? Then maybe the load in `if` (just after `switch`) is faster then this very complicated `configureEvents` of yours? Thus `configureFadeOut` fires first (by the way: why do you load the same data twice?). If this is the case, then content is loaded but not configured just as we see it. And since browsers cache data, then this only happens once.

So what is my advice? Refactor this code. First of all each button in the menu should have its own content - a unique div. You will load the data to the div. Using jQuery `.data` you will set the div to `loaded` so every other click will not trigger ajax (unless there is a reason to do so, like very dynamic data). Then clicking between buttons will only change css `display` (or fire `fadeIn` - `fadeOut`).

Next thing: why do you use `delegate`? First of all this is obsolete (use `on`) and second: does menu change during its lifetime? If it does not, then there is no point.

Finally: get rid of those `setTimeouts`. Write simple code like this:

```
show preloader --> on fadeIn callback load data -->
--> on load callback do some stuff -->
--> hide preloader
```

That's all I can say at the moment. I hope it helps a bit. If it does not, then I can only wish you luck! :)

Comment: Hi freakish, thanks I will get to it! But just to be sure, since each content will have its own div - do I load them all at page load or after a button is pressed? Secondly, if they are all loaded at page-load - won't that slow down the browser?

Comment: No, no. Every `div` is empty at the begining (otherwise there is no point in using ajax at all :) ). You do the handling code and in `$(document).ready(..)` you artifically trigger click on the default menu element (so the content of the first div is loaded at the entire page load). That's how I would do that and for example in jQuery UI tabs it is done like this (thus I believe it is a good practice). But the main issue is with the same load being called twice!

Comment: I just looked over my code again and noticed the stupid thing I did that you mentioned. So what I did was that I removed the `.load` function in the `configureVenues` and noticed that the *Venues* content doesn't load anymore. I think I'll just redo the code according to what you and Sime said and see what comes out of it :)

Comment: I'll get some sleep now and get back to it as soon as I wake up. Thanks freakish! :)

Comment: Hi freakish, I thought over your answer and over the long term this is how the website will be made to work. Many thanks!